# Release com object on runtime error

Tags: c#, com, dispose

I'm fiddling round with Excel interop at the moment.

Its all going smoothly and I'm disposing of the COM objects and everybody is happy.

What I'm wondering though is how I can reliably kill the COM object if my application crashes out?

Any suggestions welcome, I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the disposing code on the finally block of your try catch finnally block or try the putting `Application.ThreadException` event and do the disposing there.